# Equivalent definitions of limit point

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$. A point $x \in X$ is said to be a limit point of $A$ if
$$ x\in U \in \mathcal{T} \implies (U - \{ x\}) \cap A \neq \emptyset \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

In my book, it is said that above definition of a limit point is equivalent to
$$x \in \overline{A - \{x\}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

It seems to be an obvious observation so no justification is given. But I'm struggling to prove this. I managed to show $(\implies)$, but not the converse. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It does seem obvious. What is your definition of a closure?

Comment: It follows from the observation that $(U-\{x\}) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ if and only if $(A-\{x\}) \cap U \neq \emptyset$

Comment: Note that $(U\setminus \{x\})\cap A = U\cap (A\setminus \{x\})$.

Comment: The closure of $B$ is the smallest closed set containing $B$.  I now found a theorem that says that $x \in \overline{B} $ iff every open neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $B$, which concludes the missing part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One equivalent definition of the closure $\overline{B}$ of a any set $B$ is the set of all $x \in X$ so that $$\forall U: x \in U \in \mathcal{T} \implies U \cap B \neq \emptyset\tag{1}$$

This is the same as defining $\overline{B}$ as the minimal closed set containing $B$ e.g. Munkres, or almost any topology text book will cover this fact.

Applying $(1)$ to $A- \{x\}$ we see that

$$x \in \overline{A-\{x\}} \iff \forall U: x \in U \in \mathcal{T} \implies U \cap (A-\{x\}) \neq \emptyset$$

To finish the proof note that

$$U \cap (A-\{x\}) = (U-\{x\})\cap A$$

so that we get the limit point condition you defined.